# Backtrack deployed work items in TFS

Tags: tfs

In TFS, when I link a work item in a PR, the PR gets approved, merged and the a CI deployment is performed, then I bet TFS should be able to see that the linked workitem(s) have been deployed production. I shouldn't have to look into master or develop branch to see if the code I am looking for is in place.

So, when looking at that particular work item (in epic, on board, wherever) I should be able to see some kind of deployment status.

Is that an out-of-the-box feature or does that require a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "deployment status" can be checked with the linked **Pull Request** and **commit**.

Once the PR gets approved, merged and the CI deployment is performed, the code changes will be checked in. Normally we can check if the code changes are really there by navigating to the specific merged branch.

Actually, when you looking at that particular work item, you can check the linked PR and commit to know the deployment status.

- When you link a work item in a PR which is not approved and
  completed, then you can see that there is ***only*** a **Pull
  Request** with the ID under the **All Links** tap in the work item.
- Once the PR is approved and completed, you can see that there is a
  **commit** linked to the work item.

So, when you see a corresponding **Commit** linked there, that means the changes are deployed. You can also double click the linked PR and commit to open them to see the change details.

[image]

Comment: @user776686 Have you resolved the issue by above suggestion? any update?